# JavaでObjective-CやSwiftのようなDelegateを実装できるのか。

Tags: swift, java, objective-c

Javaを始める前にObjective-Cを勉強していたので、
Javaを書いているとObjective-Cのデリゲートが使えたらなと思う場面がたまにあります。
JavaでObjective-CやSwiftのようなデリゲートって行うことができるのでしょうか？

Comment: interfaceで定義したメソッドなどが、「呼び出される」タイミングなどはinterface内や別クラスで定義できますか？
例えば、ボタンが押された時に呼び出されるようにするなど。

Comment: 自己解決できました！
どうやらjavaではイベントハンドラとイベントリスナーを用いれば、私のやりたかったことができそうです。
https://sites.google.com/site/yasuda/java/du-zinoibentowo-zuoru-fang-fa

Comment: 自己解決した場合はご自身で解答を付け、後日承認なさると他の方への参考にもなって良いと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Myakuさんアドバイスありがとうございます。

>
自己解決できました！ どうやらjavaではイベントハンドラとイベントリスナーを用いれば、私のやりたかったことができそうです。
参考:
http://sites.google.com/site/yasuda/java/du-zinoibentowo-zuoru-fang-fa

Answer (score 0):

JavaだとInterfaceが近いと思います。